Laravel 11 CSRF Token Mismatch Error on API Registration
I'm currently developing a Laravel 11 application with a React front-end, and I'm running into a persistent "CSRF token mismatch" error when attempting to register a user via the API. I have tried several methods to resolve this issue but haven't had any success.
Details:
I have a form in my React application that sends user registration data to my Laravel backend. Here’s the relevant code for my Register component:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; 

export default function Register() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get CSRF token from the meta tag
    const csrfTokenMeta = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

    if (csrfTokenMeta) {
      console.log('CSRF Token:', csrfTokenMeta);
    } else {
      console.error('CSRF Token meta tag not found.');
    }

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/register', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfTokenMeta, // Include CSRF token
        },
      });

      alert('User registered successfully!');
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Registration error:', error);
      alert('Error registering user. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {/* Form fields for first name, last name, email, and password */}
    </form>
  );
}

Problem:
When I submit the form, I receive the following error:
{message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"}

What I’ve Tried:
CSRF Token Verification:
I've ensured the CSRF token is being correctly fetched and sent in the request headers.
Session Configuration:
Verified that config/session.php is set to use the file driver and same_site is set to lax.
CORS Configuration:
Updated config/cors.php to ensure the API endpoint is included:
'paths' => ['api/*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

Inspect Network Requests
Checked the network requests in the browser's developer tools and confirmed that the CSRF token is being sent correctly in the headers.
 Cleared Cache 
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan cache:clear

 CSRF token initialization
In my app.blade.php, I included the CSRF token like this:
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">


CSRF and API dont mix. use tokens to secure your requests. you talk about setting CSRF in a blade but you call the request with your react app. If it was that easy to fetch the csrf from pages and send them into a form submission request, then the CSRF itself would be useless.
